# Partial pressure of gases in liquid

Tags: physical-chemistry

I was trying to understand what partial pressure of a gas in a liquid means and found the following sentence in a book I don't get it fully. What does it mean, can someone please explain? (What does it mean by a gas being in equilibrium with liquid?)

> Partial pressure of a gas in solution refers to the pressure of the
>    gas in the gas phase **in equilibrium with the liquid.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What illustration? Pressure out of equilibrium could have any value.

Comment: What do you mean by 'out of equilibrium'?

Comment: I have reworded my question.

Comment: Equilibrium of dissolution/vaporisation process...

Comment: @Mithoron I understand the purpose of your comment, but I think "What is your problem really?" was misunderstood to be insulting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a gas species dissolved in a liquid.  The liquid is the solvent, and the gas species is the solute.  Suppose that the gas phase in contact with the liquid consists of mixture of several gases, and one of these gases is the gas species of interest.  In order for the concentration of the dissolved gas species in the liquid to remain constant, so that no more of the gas species dissolves nor does some of the gas species come out of solution, the partial pressure of the species in the gas phase must be at a certain equilibrium value.